# Please advise on the WSDL

Tags: web-services, proxy, wsdl, cxf, mule

I have created a WSDL to create a greeting service.  Given below is the WSDL.

I am using thsi wsdl to create a generate and expose a web-service using the cxf:proxy-service in mule.

This is giving me errors.

Please review and help me undertand what is the problem with this WSDL.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions name="HelloService"
    targetNamespace="http://example.org/HelloService"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.org/HelloService" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"  
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example.org/HelloService" >
              <xsd:element name="LastName">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="lName" type="xsd:string"/>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="FirstName">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="fName" type="xsd:string"/>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>

              <xsd:element name="Greeting">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="greet" type="xsd:string"/>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="shortRequest">
        <wsdl:part type="tns:LastName" name="lastName"/>
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="fullRequest">
        <wsdl:part type="tns:FirstName" name="firstName"/>
        <wsdl:part type="tns:LastName" name="lastName"/>
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="greetingResponse">
        <wsdl:part type="tns:greeting" name="greetings"/>
      </wsdl:message>   


      <wsdl:portType name="HelloServicePortType">

        <wsdl:operation name="simpleGreeting">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:shortRequest" name="shortRequest" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:greetingResponse" name="greetingResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="fullGreeting">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:fullRequest" name="fullRequest" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:greetingResponse"  name="greetingResponseFull" />
        </wsdl:operation>

      </wsdl:portType>


    <wsdl:binding name="HelloServiceSOAP" type="tns:HelloServicePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="simpleGreeting">
          <soap:operation soapAction=""  style="document" />
          <wsdl:input name="shortRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output name="greetingResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

       <wsdl:operation name="fullGreeting">
          <soap:operation soapAction=""  style="document" />
          <wsdl:input name="fullRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output name="greetingResponseFull">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

      </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="ProxyService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:HelloServiceSOAP" name="HelloServiceSOAPB">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloService" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>     
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Please help me if there is something wrong in my WSDL. 
It is not working when I use it in mule cxf:proxy-service.

FGiven below si the Mule Flow which is using this WSDL to expose service.

```
<flow name="WS_In">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/HelloService" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service  wsdlLocation="classpath:globalid3.wsdl" namespace="http://example.org/HelloService" service="ProxyService" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>        
    <component>             
        <prototype-object class="com.example.ServiceProxy">                                                         
        </prototype-object>
    </component>        
    <echo-component></echo-component>
    <logger level="INFO"        />
</flow>
```

and the Error is :

```
org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Lifecycle Manager 'WS_In.stage1' phase 'start' does not support phase 'dispose'
at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:156)
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the error you are getting and how you are consuming the web service.

Comment: Also: why using a `prototype-object`? Do you really want a new instance created for each request?

Comment: yes. I am looking for new object for each request.  I got it working. The problem is with the WSDL I guess. Given below is the answer.

Comment: My proposed solution below doesn't create a new object for each request (it uses a message processor) but you can adapt it to use a `prototype-object` instead. This said I would be curious to hear about your use case and the justification for creating one new object per request...

Comment: I was trying the mediator paattern. So this component will internally invoke another flow with some correlation id and polls from a response queue where the response is posted. FOr this reason wanted to have individual object for each request as the correaltion object is existing inside the component onCall method.

Comment: You colution looks good for me. But I have doubt. What is the difference between the Component and Custom-processor. Is tehre any advantage of using the custom-processor instead of Component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a casing issue in your WSDL. Instead of:

```
  <wsdl:message name="greetingResponse">
    <wsdl:part type="tns:greeting" name="greetings"/>
  </wsdl:message>
```

you should have:

```
  <wsdl:message name="greetingResponse">
    <wsdl:part type="tns:Greeting" name="greetings"/>
  </wsdl:message>
```

With this fixed, the following produces a web service that works fine when called from SOAPui:

```
<flow name="WS_In">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/HelloService"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:globalid3.wsdl"
            namespace="http://example.org/HelloService" service="ProxyService" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <custom-processor class="com.example.ServiceProxy" />
</flow>
```

Message processor:

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor;

public class ServiceProxy implements MessageProcessor
{
    private final static QName SIMPLE_GREETING = new QName("http://example.org/HelloService",
        "simpleGreeting");

    public MuleEvent process(final MuleEvent event) throws MuleException
    {
        final QName operation = event.getFlowVariable("cxf_operation");

        if (operation.equals(SIMPLE_GREETING))
        {
            final String lastName = event.getMuleContext()
                .getExpressionLanguage()
                .evaluate("xpath('/lastName').text", event);

            final String responseXml = "<greetings><greet>Hi " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(lastName)
                                       + "</greet></greetings>";

            event.getMessage().setPayload(responseXml);
            return event;
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(operation.getLocalPart() + " " + operation.getNamespaceURI()
                                                + " " + operation.getPrefix());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one way to do this using cxf:jaxws-service, but you'll need to generate the service class. Take a look [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-CXFWS-ReliableMessagingTutorial)  on how to do this.

After that you can configure the service in a very simple way.

```
        <cxf:jaxws-service
            serviceClass="mypackage.webservices.MyServicePortType"
            validationEnabled="false">
        </cxf:jaxws-service>
```

Answer (score 0):

The flow that is working is as below.

```
<flow name="WS_In">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/HelloService" exchange-pattern="request-response">
            <cxf:proxy-service  wsdlLocation="classpath:helloservice.wsdl" namespace="http://example.org/HelloService" service="ProxyService" />
        </http:inbound-endpoint>        
        <component>             
            <prototype-object class="com.example.ServiceProxy">     
            </prototype-object>
        </component>        
        <echo-component></echo-component>
        <logger level="INFO"        />
 </flow>
```

And the WSDL is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions name="HelloService"
    targetNamespace="http://example.org/HelloService"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.org/HelloService" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"  
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

      <wsdl:message name="shortRequest">
        <wsdl:part type="xsd:string" name="lastName"/>
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="fullRequest">
        <wsdl:part type="xsd:string" name="firstName"/>
        <wsdl:part type="xsd:string" name="lastName"/>
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="greetingResponse">
        <wsdl:part type="xsd:string" name="greetings"/>
      </wsdl:message>   


      <wsdl:portType name="HelloServicePortType">

        <wsdl:operation name="simpleGreeting">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:shortRequest" name="shortRequest" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:greetingResponse" name="greetingResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="fullGreeting">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:fullRequest" name="fullRequest" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:greetingResponse"  name="greetingResponseFull" />
        </wsdl:operation>

      </wsdl:portType>


    <wsdl:binding name="HelloServiceSOAP" type="tns:HelloServicePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="simpleGreeting">
          <soap:operation soapAction=""  style="document" />
          <wsdl:input name="shortRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output name="greetingResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

       <wsdl:operation name="fullGreeting">
          <soap:operation soapAction=""  style="document" />
          <wsdl:input name="fullRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output name="greetingResponseFull">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

      </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="ProxyService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:HelloServiceSOAP" name="HelloServiceSOAPB">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloService" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Thanks everyone for your help and support.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, complete with parsing of request and generation of response...