# Why does Mule returns WSDL soapAction as double quoted string

Tags: web-services, soap, mule

I've the task of routing message to different jms queues based on the soapAction. I'm using `<cxf:proxy-service>` so basically there is no other way to find what operation was invoked other than populating `soapAction` attribute in WSDL (unless someone tells me otherwise). So this is what I was trying to achieve:

```
<choice>
  <when expression="message.inboundProperties['SOAPAction'] == 'submitOrderStatus'">
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="mviq.1122.result" />
  </when>
 ....
</choice>
```

But the above code does not evaluate to true even though if I print the expression shown below using logger, I get `"submitOrderStatus"`

```
<logger message="SoapAction is #[message.inboundProperties['SOAPAction']]" level="INFO" />
```

After banging my head for too long and hours of dissection of log files, I realized that all the values of properties are unquoted except for `SOAPAction`. 
So changing my flow to this saved me:

```
<when expression="message.inboundProperties['SOAPAction'] == '&quot;submitOrderStatus&quot;'">
    <logger message="Can evaluate this message.inboundProperties['SOAPAction'] == '&quot;submitOrderStatus&quot;'" level="INFO" />
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="mviq.1122.result" />
</when>
```

I'm very curious to know why does Mule returns SoapAction as double quoted String

**EDIT:**  SoapUI send this over the wire. I'm not sure why `SOAPAction` is quoted.

```
POST http://localhost:61005/mvi/service HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "submitOrderStatus"
Content-Length: 5355
Host: localhost:61005
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)`
```

Below is part of my wsdl:

```
<wsdl:operation name="submitOrderStatus">
     <soap:operation soapAction="submitOrderStatus" style="document"/>
     <wsdl:input name="submitOrderStatusRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output name="submitOrderStatusResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is no other way to find what operation was invoked other than populating soapAction attribute in WSDL

This is not correct: see how I get the operation from the `cxf_operation` flow variable in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14163660/387927

> I'm very curious to know why does Mule returns SoapAction as double quoted String

SOAPAction headers are quoted as per the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/soap11/#_Toc478383528

So your expression should be:

```
<when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['SOAPAction'] == '&quote;submitOrderStatus&quote;']">
```

Comment: Thanks David for the link. It makes sense now. Again, would appreciate if you can explain the difference of using `#[ ]` versus not using it in expression as part of message router because I see the same result in both the cases.

Comment: The canonical form for expressions is to use `#[ ]` around them. Mule sometimes in some places allow you to not use the `#[ ]` but it is recommended to always use them to be sure of the result.